# Call python function from other py file what goes in __init__.py

Tags: python, django, server, backend

I have a python file, with a function that I want to call in multiple places. But I want the file with the function to be in the home directory and not have to store it in every directory I want to use it. Is this possible?

For example lets say I have a py file called add.py, and it is in the home directory and its this

```
def add(b):
    a = 3
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b
```

And then in a sub directory I want to call add, how could I do that, I know if there in the same directory I could do `from a import add`

But in my case the add function is more complex and I want to call it in a bunch of different places without having to store multiples of the file in each directory. 
I know I could use **init**.py, but what goes in the field?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Importing modules from parent folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the home directory to `PYTHONPATH` and then it would be possible to do `from a import add`.

To programmatically add a directory to `PYTHONPATH` , you can use `sys.path`.

Example -

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/home/directory')
```

After doing the above you would be able to directly import any scripts that exist in the home directory. Example if in home directory there is an `a.py` with add function, after above lines you would be able to do -

```
from a import add
```

Outside python, you can also set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to contain your home directory, and then you would be able to import any python scripts in the home directory directly (from anywhere) -

Example of setting the PYTHONPATH in bash -

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH;/path/to/home/directory
```

Comment: OK, Im trying this on my comp, and right now a.py is in `/Doucments/py scripts` and b.py is in `/Doucments/py scripts/test` so I put `sys.path.append('/test')`, but it doesn't work, what should I be putting? Does it matter that there is a space in the file `py scripts`?

Comment: You want to import `a` into `b` right? So shouldn't you be putting path of `a` ? Put complete path of `a` , not `b`